# iOS Distribution Profile - Could not launch [App] process launch failed: failed to get task for process 1339

Tags: ios, xcode

Using a distribution profile, I'm trying to launch my app onto an actual iPhone from Xcode 7 in order to test push notification using the debugger.  After researching this topic, I've come across a few answers that suggest it's not possible to use Xcode's debugger with apps created with distribution profiles; I need to use a developer profile.  But, unfortunately, the push notification service that I'm testing has been set up using a production certificate which is why I can't use a developer profile.

If I launch the app directly on my phone, the error doesn't appear; however, I don't have the option of using Xcode's debugger.

1. Are there really no solutions for using Xcode's debugger with a distribution app?  Is there a setting in Xcode or a plist modification that will enable debugging for a distribution app?
2. What options do I have for debugging notifications that come from a PNS using a production certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox certificate and apple server endpoint are here for this, if you're done with testing in sandbox mode then production will work, if it's not the only problem could be a bad certificate and you can correct it also after release.
Anyway you can test apns in production mode using an ad hoc distribution certificate on apps distributed with testflight or Fabric, for instance.

Comment: I understand the purpose of sandboxes and dev certificates but my question isn't about why I'm getting the error... I want to know how I can use Xcode's debugger with an app bundled with a distribution certificate, if it's possible.  In my situation, I don't have the option of using dev certificates with a sandbox environment.

Comment: I think it's not possible... the token Apple send to you in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken will not be valid for production environment apns.